# Digitalmicrograph DM script - updating pulldown items from another dialog

Tags: drop-down-menu, dialog, refresh, items, dm-script

I am working on a DM script that creates a technique which contains a few dialogs.
In this script I am trying to update the pulldown menu items in one dialog from inside another dialog.

I currently have a button inside the dialog with the pulldown menu called "update" which calls a function inside the dialog class that is called "updateDialog".
This function removes all pulldown menu items and then inserts all the items stored in a taglist.
It also changes the state of a few buttons in that dialog.

This update button works perfectly.

Now if I call this updateDialog function from inside the other dialog, the button states change as they should, but the pulldown menu does not update.

Does anyone know why this happens and/or if there is a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Example code:

```
taggroup menuitems = newtaglist()
object firstdialog, seconddialog

interface I_seconddialog{
    void updatedropdowndialog(object self);
}

class firstdialog : uiframe{
    void additemresponse (object self){
        number items = menuitems.taggroupcounttags()+1
        menuitems.taggroupinserttagasstring(infinity(), "Created item #"+items)
        menuitems.taggroupopenbrowserwindow(0)
        seconddialog.updatedropdowndialog()
    }

    taggroup createdialog (object self){
        taggroup dialog, dialogitems, additembutton
        dialog = DLGCreateDialog("first_dialog", dialogItems)
        additembutton = DLGCreatePushButton("Add pulldown item", "additemresponse")
        
        dialogitems.dlgaddelement(additembutton)
        return dialog
    }   

    object init (object self){
        return self.super.init( self.createdialog() )
    }
}

class seconddialog : uiframe{
    number isbuttonenabled
    void updatedropdowndialog (object self){
        // Change the state of the state button to show that that does work
        isbuttonenabled = abs(isbuttonenabled-1)
        self.Setelementisenabled("statebutton",isbuttonenabled);
    
        // Empty the dropdown as the menuitems list might be completely different
        taggroup dropdown = self.lookupelement("dropdown")
        taggroup dropdown_items
        dropdown.taggroupgettagastaggroup("Items",dropdown_items)
        dropdown_items.taggroupdeletealltags()  

        // Add the current tags in menuitems to the dropdown
        for(number i=0;i<menuitems.taggroupcounttags();i++){
            string item_name
            menuitems.taggroupgetindexedtagasstring(i,item_name)
            dropdown.dlgaddchoiceitementry(item_name)   
        }
    }

    taggroup createdialog (object self){
        taggroup dialog, dialogitems, dropdown, updatebutton, statebutton
        dialog = DLGCreateDialog("second_dialog", dialogItems)
        taggroup initial_items
        dropdown = DLGCreateChoice(initial_items,0,"dropdownchange").dlgidentifier("dropdown")
        dropdown.dlgaddchoiceitementry("Initial item")
        updatebutton = DLGCreatePushButton("Update dropdown", "updatedropdowndialog")
        statebutton = DLGCreatePushButton("state changes", "stateresponse").dlgidentifier("statebutton")
        
        dialogitems.dlgaddelement(dropdown)
        dialogitems.dlgaddelement(updatebutton)
        dialogitems.dlgaddelement(statebutton)
        return dialog
    }   

    object init (object self){
        isbuttonenabled = 1
        return self.super.init( self.createdialog() )
    }
}

void main(){
    String techniqueName = "Example"
    Image techniqueIcon := RGBImage( "Test icon", 4, 75, 75 )
    techniqueIcon = RGB( icol, irow, iradius )
    object technique = CreateTechnique( techniqueName, techniqueIcon )
    firstdialog = Alloc( firstdialog ).Init()

    String taskName = "First dialog"
    Number taskID = RegisterWorkflowTask( firstdialog, taskName )
    Number bOpenByDefault = 1
    Number bEssential = 0                
    AddWorkflowTask( technique, taskID, bEssential, bOpenByDefault )
    seconddialog = Alloc( seconddialog ).Init()
    
    taskName = "Second dialog"
    taskID = RegisterWorkflowTask( seconddialog, taskName )
    bOpenByDefault = 1
    bEssential = 0                
    AddWorkflowTask( technique, taskID, bEssential, bOpenByDefault )

    AddCustomTechnique( technique )
}

main()
```

Comment: Could you provide a slimmed-down code in your question that shows what you describe and can be used as basis for an answer-post, please? Ideally, this is a stand-alone code section that you can directly add to your question post (using the *edit*).

Comment: Hi Bmyguest, I have quickly made some code that shows the issue.
If you click the add pulldown item, it triggers the updatedropdowndialog function.
It should update the dropdown AND toggle the state of the button, but it only toggles the state.
If you click the update dropdown button in the second dialog, it triggers the same function, but then it works as it should.

Comment: I can confirm this issue. In the documentation it sais for the `DLGInvalid` method: "Sets the 'Invalid' attribute for a modified element. **Used for run-time update of dialog displays**". I tried it together with `UIFrame::validateView()` but it didn't work. Note that all `UIFrame` methods work while working directly on the dialog objects does not work. I remember having had this issue too, but I can't find where and how I solved it.

Comment: Thank you for your script. I've tested it (see below), but I don't see the problem. Could you elaborate? (And which GMS version are you useing?)

Comment: Oh, it might just have been a bug which has in the meantime been fixed already. I've tested your script on GMS 3.4.0 now as well, and there the drop-down is *not* updating.

Comment: Ah allright! I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks for testing, I will check if I can update my version of GMS to a later version.

Comment: I am having similar issues with number fields and lists that are not updating. Could be caused by the same bug.

Comment: I am currently using version 3.32 by the way.

Comment: @Merijn If this isn't on an online system (installed with hardware), I would definitely recommend updating to the 3.4 version - it has a lot of new features. 3.4.2 is the currently available latest release, but you might also opt for the limited-edition 3.4.1 "Covid" if you are interested in accessing otherwise non-free features like Quantification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**<sup>Not an answer (yet), but a longer clarification comment</sup>**

I'm testing your script code on GMS 3.4.2 and this is the behavior I see, running the script (once) right after GMS start:

> 1. Custom technique is added:
>     [image]
> 2. It shows two dialogs initially as:
>     [image]
> 3. Pressing "Update dropdown" on the Second dialog toggles the "state
>    changes" button enabled/disabled:
>     [image]
> 4. Pressing the "Add pulldown item" button on the First dialog each
>    time adds to the drop-down *and* toggles the "state changes" button in
>    the Second dialog (and displays the tagList of entries):
>     [image]

**Isn't that exactly the intended behavior ?**